# Django tests are deleting production data, only work when running all tests at once

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-testing, django-tests, postgres-9.6

First off, this is Django 1.9.13.  I realize this is an unsupported version, but I have to use it for reasons. The database is postgres 9.6.

I have a project that runs about 40 tests divided amongst a few files.  All test cases are `TransactionTestCase` that load their own fixtures through `fixture = ['fixture_name.json']`  I use fixtures in the `app/fixtures` directory that are akin to

```
base_data.json 
test_a_data.json
test_b_data.json
...
```

Base data is used in most if not all test cases.  But the other fixtures are used in 1 or few tests.

The settings to run it are

```
'test': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'HOST': 0.0.0.0,
    'PORT': 5432,
    'NAME': <database>,
    'USER': <user>,
    'PASSWORD': <pass>,
    'TEST': {
        'NAME': 'test_database'
    }
}
```

When running the following command, it runs fine

```
python manage.py app.test -v 1 --keepdb
```

However, when running individual test cases it fails

```
python manage.py app.test.test_A.ATestCase -v 1 --keepdb
```

This fails with

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/app/fixtures/test_a_data.json': Could not load <object>(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "<uniq_constraint_name>"
DETAIL:  Key <key> already exists.
```

as if the fixture is being loaded twice.  I have tried inspecting the SQL Django is using and found that the object in question is only loaded once.  However, the object *does* exist in `<database>` just not `<test_database>`.

This leads me to the second portion of my problem.

When I run the full test suite, it runs fine, even tests where the above fixtures were erroring when run by themselves.

However, after a successful test suite run, subsequent test suite runs fail, and when inspecting `<database>` all the tables are now empty.  I have attempted to debug this by inspecting SQL queries, but the logs stop after 4MB. And since I can't successfully run a single `TestCase` I can't get to the point that the table rows are deleted and see what might be tearing down the data in the db.

I have scoured any Django testing docs I could find and was not able to find anything that would explain why `<database>` is either being deleted when a test runs successfuly, nor why the single test cases are failing on their own, but not alongside the full test suite.

Comment: What happens if you don't use --keepdb? Also, have you tried specifying a TEST_DB in the settings?

Comment: @dfundako removing `--keepdb` does not affect any of the issues I laid out in the OP, same errors, same conditions.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-TEST

Comment: I deleted the comment saying I couldn't find it meaning to create a new one responding with something more constructive, like "do you have an example?" just before you responded. Apologies!

Comment: @dfundako I've tried both specifying the test db and not, same result each time.